# How do I find the wallet that Bitcoin was sent to?

Tags: wallet

How do I find the wallet that Bitcoin was sent to?  I was new to Bitcoin and created at wallets in at least 2 places (Armory and Coinbase) but all are showing zero.

Comment: Why do you think bitcoin was sent to a wallet exactly? What information do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know one of two things

- the sending address, or
- the transaction id

You can put either of these into any [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) and find out the receiving addresses.

Once you know the receiving addresses you can open each of your wallets, ask the wallet to display all the receiving addresses it has previously generated. Don't ask the wallet to generate a new receiving address - that will just make it create a new address. There will be a less obvious option in a menu that will show all addresses used so far.

Once you have the list of addresses in each wallet you can find if any of them match any of the receiving addresses from the transaction shown in the blockchain explorer.

---

There is no way for anyone else to find out which non-custodial wallets (the best sort) contain an address - that information is not public.

If you have a custodial wallet - you can ask the custodian for help. For example, if you have a coinbase account, you could ask coinbase customer support for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the public address that it came from, you can check the block explorer for the most recent transaction.